# Why is component along x axis = 0 if body in pointing along Y axis?

Tags: vectors

[image]
[image]

There is a projectile motion of a rock in the diagram.

I made its acceleration due to gravity pointing in downwards direction.My question is that why do we say that it’s component along x axis will be 0.

Have I drawn the diagram correct ?

What can we comment about the acceleration along y axis(Not exactly).It said online that it should’ve be - g but I couldn’t understand it

I also did check a similar question like this on physics stack exchange but it has no clear objectified answer.

Comment: 1. Do you understand how vectors can be broken down into components? 2. What is "y axis (not exactly)"? Is it along the direction of travel of the rock?

Comment: I have broken a or g in such a way that it’s components are ax and ay.Yes i do understand how to break them.

Comment: Since there have to be two components , So ay(not exactly) is the 2nd component of g.

Comment: Components, when you set them up, must be perpendicular to each other (which you did not draw correctly).